# What is the main reason for pygame.init()

Tags: python, pygame

I am learning Pygame in Python and am having trouble understanding the purpose of the `pygame.init()` function. Can someone explain its functionality and why it's necessary to use in Pygame? Tutorials I've watched state that this function "initializes" Pygame, but doesn't importing `pygame` already bring all of its modules into the program? The tutorials also say that `pygame.init()` will import all the required Pygame modules, but again, doesn't `import pygame` already import all the modules?

I've read the Stackoverflow post ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58868486/what-exactly-does-pygame-init-do#:~:text=www.pygame.org-,pygame.,individual%20modules%20manually%2C%20but%20pygame.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58868486/what-exactly-does-pygame-init-do#:%7E:text=www.pygame.org-,pygame.,individual%20modules%20manually%2C%20but%20pygame.)) but I don't understand the words "pygame.init() initialize all imported pygame modules".

Comment: If you couldn't import the library without initialization happening, then code analysis and QA tools that depend on dynamic analysis couldn't be used on pygame-dependent codebases from an environment without a GUI; it would break any kind of reasonable continuous integration workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(BTW, this is not specific to pygame) Generally there is a difference between "loading/importing code" and "initialization". For example:

```py
# foo.py

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

```py
import foo  # code is now loaded/imported

my_foo_obj = foo.Foo(123)  # a Foo is now initialized
```

In the same manner, `pygame.init()` suggests it's designed to have a distinction between loading & initialization.

You might ask, "why make this distinction?". Indeed, loading and initialization could be coupled together:

```py
# bar.py

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, value):
        # maybe also do expensive computation
        self.value = value

default_bar = Bar(123)
```

```py
import bar  # code is loaded and then a default_bar is also initailized

print(bar.default_bar.value)
```

But this way, you can only ever have one `default_bar`, and you lose control of when the initialization cost of "the expensive thing" is taken. For example, perhaps you want to show a loading screen/loading bar to the user before the computer occupies itself initializing your game and appears to "freeze".

Comment: Could you give a Pygame specific example?